# Replace ubuntu unity launcher with dock

Tags: unity, launcher, dock

I know it is possible to disable/move unity launcher in ubuntu 11.10, but what about 13.04? I would like to completely disable unity launcher and use some sort of dock, or move unity launcher to the bottom of desktop. Is it possible to do so?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's launcher can't be moved from it's position. You can hide it and use docky or cairo dock if you wanted to.

Comment: Okay, but if you use docky or cairo dock, launcher becomes absolutely useless. That is why I am searching for how to get rid of it.

Comment: If you don't like the launcher, your best is to use a different desktop envoriment like Cinnamon,KDE,Gnome 3, or MATE.